# Unable to format and use USB flash drive in Windows

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I have a San Disk Cruzer Blade 16 GB USB flash drive which doesn't show up in Windows when I plug it in. So, when I go to Disk Management, it shows the following:
(Disk 1 is the flash drive)

[image: Disk Management Window]

When I try to format it, I get:

[image: Error Message]

As suggested by the error message, when I try to assign a drive letter, I get:

[image: Error Message]

When I delete the volume in Windows and create a New Simple Volume with NTFS file system, I get the following:

[image: Warning Message]

And it's still not visible.

But the flash drive works fine with Linux. I can format and use it.
What's the problem that's happening in Windows?

Comment: Right click and delete the existing partition then create a new partition and format it. Windows doesn’t read Linux file systems.

Comment: I didn't format it with a Linux file system. I formatted it with a NTFS file system in Linux. Still not visible in Windows. Also, I've edited my question, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access to the flash drive only on Linux, try to format it in NTFS or Fat32, you will be able to see ir both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I formatted it with a NTFS file system in Linux. Still only visible in Linux, not Windows.